# Getting distinct rows on SQL query with multiple IIF columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server I am creating a view that shows if a record in table CONTACTS has certain tags in a different table TAGS.

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    contacts.ID, contacts.NAME,
    IIF(tags.tag = 'A', 1, 0) as A,
    IIF(tags.tag = 'B', 1, 0) as B,
    IIF(tags.tag = 'C', 1, 0) as C,
    IIF(tags.tag = 'D', 1, 0) as D
FROM
    contacts 
LEFT JOIN
    TAGS ON contacts.ID = TAGS.CONTACT_ID
```

I would like the results like this:

```
ID     NAME     A     B     C     D
------------------------------------
1      BOB      1     0     0     1
1      Charlie  1     0     1     0
```

but I get

```
ID     NAME     A     B     C     D
------------------------------------
1      BOB      1     0     0     0
1      BOB      0     0     0     1
1      Charlie  1     0     0     0
1      Charlie  0     0     1     0
```

Must be something I overlook, but I can't find it.

Comment: hint : `max()`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by`:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.NAME,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.tag = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as A,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.tag = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as B,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.tag = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as C,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.tag = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as D
FROM contacts c LEFT JOIN
     TAGS t
     ON c.ID = t.CONTACT_ID
GROUP BY c.ID, c.NAME;
```

Note changes the query:

- Introduced table aliases.  These make the query easier to write and to read.
- Removed the `SELECT DISTINCT`, because you really want a `GROUP BY`.
- Changed `IIF()` to `CASE`.  I see no reason to use a function designed for backward compatibility to MS Access over the SQL standard function.

Answer (score 3):

You need simply use `GROUP BY` clause + `MAX` aggreate instead of `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT contacts.ID, contacts.NAME
                 , MAX(IIF(tags.tag = 'A', 1, 0)) as A
                 , MAX(IIF(tags.tag = 'B', 1, 0)) as B
                 , MAX(IIF(tags.tag = 'C', 1, 0)) as C
                 , MAX(IIF(tags.tag = 'D', 1, 0)) as D
FROM            contacts LEFT  JOIN
                     TAGS ON contacts.ID = TAGS.CONTACT_ID
group by
    contacts.ID, contacts.NAME
```

*As Gordon Linoff says, use of standard SQL `case when` is more compatible with all the database (postgres, oracle, sql server ...)*

```
IIF(tags.tag = 'A', 1, 0)
```

is equivalent to

```
CASE WHEN tags.tag = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT contacts.ID, contacts.NAME
                 , MAX(IIF(tags.tag = 'A', 1, 0)) as A
                 , MAX(IIF(tags.tag = 'B', 1, 0)) as B
                 , MAX(IIF(tags.tag = 'C', 1, 0)) as C
                 , MAX(IIF(tags.tag = 'D', 1, 0) as D
FROM            contacts LEFT  JOIN
                     TAGS ON contacts.ID = TAGS.CONTACT_ID
GROUP BY contacts.ID, contacts.NAME
```